# Content depending on link which was clicked

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to build a page, which is build like this sketch i did. [sketch HP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l2mm.png)

The content area should show specific content depending on the link (AAAAA, BBBBB, there should also be links in Menu 3 and 4) which was clicked by a visitor. 
I want to do this in typo3, but I dont quite know how to. If i make a whole pagetree with all the pages i get a menu i cant use on the site.

I think the answer is quite near to me but i cant find it.

I'm quite new to typo3, I already built 2 pages with it but with completely other concepts.

Thanks Already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does it mean *I get a menu I can't use on the site* ???
*(That's a rhetoric question)*

In TYPO3 you can create as many menus as you wish and they can represent **any** scope of pages that you wish, you can for an instance create menu that takes only sub-pages of some page (`special = directory`) , or even you can point pages you want to use in menu one-by-one (`special = list`). Also you can decide how many levels of the page-tree structure you will use in the menu (by adding next levels into your HMENU TypoScript) etc. etc.

Actually the *open* page-tree structure of TYPO3 is one of its main benefits, which definitely wins with other approaches i.e. category/article approach of Joomla or tag/post approach of WordPress - especially in large, advanced portals.

Take a look at the HMENU documentation, especially at [**"The .special property"**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#the-special-property) part

Your structure may look like on the screenshot, where pages Menu 1 - Menu 4 are just shortcuts to first sub-page, then you can build 4 HMENUs with `special = directory` where
`special.value = [UID of Menu page]`

[image: sample tree structure]

**TIP:** you don't need to build each `lib.x_menu` from the scratch as you can *copy* the object into new one and change only some params i.e. (*from your sample*):

```
lib.field_topleftmenu= HMENU
lib.field_topleftmenu {
   special = directory
   special.value = 2
   // etc...
}

lib.field_bottomleftmenu < lib.field_topleftmenu
lib.field_bottomleftmenu.special.value = 3

lib.field_toprightmenu < lib.field_topleftmenu
lib.field_toprightmenu.special.value = 4

// etc...
```

This way, you'll have identical styling for all menus, but ech will have different *start point* (declared in `special.value`)

Comment: I knew it would be quite easy. I'm going to try it with this approach and give you feedback - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code i used for one menu, it is showing only the submenu ('aaa', 'bbb' for menu1, 'bbb', 'ccc' for menu2 and so on)

```
lib.field_topleftmenu= HMENU
lib.field_topleftmenu {
special = directory
special.value = 2
1 = TMENU
1 {

    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li >|</li>
      ATagTitle.field = 1
       #  = 1

    }  
  ACT = 1
  ACT{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      ATagTitle.field = 1
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      ATagParams = class="activemenu"
    }
    IFSUB{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li >|</li>
      ATagTitle.field = 1
    }
}
} 



lib.field_botleftmenu = HMENU 
lib.field_botleftmenu {
...
}
```